# Creating XML sequences with zeep / python

Tags: python, soap, xsd, wsdl, zeep

I am using zeep (Python 3.6) to interface with a SOAP API, and working with a WSDL schema which contains this section:

```
<xs:element name="passengers">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="passenger" type="com:PassengerType"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

So I'd like my zeep-generated XML to look like this:

```
<book:passengers>
    <book:passenger>
        ...redacted...
    </book:passenger>
</book:passengers>
```

My first attempt at achieving this with Zeep looked like this:

```
passengers = [factories.PassengerType()]
```

However, when sending this to my SOAP API, this generated the following error:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zeep/xsd/elements/element.py", line 220, in validate
  "Missing element %s" % (self.name), path=render_path)
zeep.exceptions.ValidationError: Missing element passenger (createBookingRecordRequest.passengers)
```

I believe this is because my 'passengers' attribute should contain a Zeep object with the tag name "passenger", which would contain my list of elements. I've tried tinkering with the `zeep.xsd.AnyType` to achieve this, but haven't succeeded yet.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Answering my own question as I've now solved it, and not received any other answers.

The root of this problem is that I am trying to create XML element that is not explicitly defined as a type by my SOAP API's WSDL. This is OK though, as Zeep will still be generating type objects for it, it just won't be assigning those types to a particular name, so we have to jump through a few extra hoops to get at those types. This is what it took me a little time to figure out.

You can get at these objects by accessing them through any parent type. They are stored in an attribute named `elements` as a list of 2-tuples. In this case, my `PassengerType` objects are supposed to be contained by a sequence container with the attribute name 'passengers'. If, for example, my parent type is named `ParentType`, I could use this 'passengers' sequence like so:

```
passengers = dict(ParentType.elements)['passengers'](
    PassengerType(),
    ...
    PassengerType()
)
```

Here, we are turning the elements object into a dict (exploiting the fact that it's a list of 2-tuples where the first item is a string of the attribute name), and then pulling the elements out by name.

The resultant object can be passed directly into `ParentType` like:

```
ParentType(passengers=passengers)
```

Simple.

One other alternative I discovered is to explicitly build the type with zeep's `xsd` objects. Example shown below.

```
from lxml import etree
from zeep import xsd

PassengersType = xsd.ComplexType(
    xsd.Sequence([
        xsd.Element('passengers', PassengerType, min_occurs=1, max_occurs='unbounded')
    ]), qname=etree.QName("{http://example.com/schema}passengers")
)
```

I think this isn't as nice, but might be useful to someone landing here.

Comment: How are you obtaining/creating `PassengerType`?

Comment: In this case, `PassengerType` is a type that is defined and named in my WSDL.

Comment: I had to do `dict(ParentType.elements)['passengers']([one, two three])` in my case, in case it helps anyone (I'm just trying to hack together some SOAP calls, didn't dig into what's going on here!)